# CSS and JS sometimes not loaded in localhost even though clear browser cache

Tags: css, asp.net, localhost

I'm working on a web application using ASP.net.
Sometimes the .css and .js files are not working while debugging with localhost.

When I upload the page to the webserver all is working fine, so it must be a local problem with the localhost.

Normally it helps to clear the cache or use a different browser.
But now none of the browsers are working, even though clearing the cache (I tried chrome, IE and Edge). By inspecting the page I get the error

> 404 not found

The files are included like this:

`<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

The path should also be ok:

`http://localhost:63714/Styles/Site.css`

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Can you check your folder path in your project? Did the `Style` folder located on the root path of the project or is it inside another folder?

Comment: the `Style` folder is in the root path of the project